# Get Loading page name with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way i can identify which page is calling my JavaScript file.

I have single JavaScript file for say 5 pages and in that file i have jQuery like.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {    
    GetDataForPage1();
    GetDataForPage2();
});
```

GetDataForPage1 get data from API and render in Page1 and similarly GetDataForPage2 render data for Page2. 
Now when Page1 call document.ready by default both function will be called, Which i dont want to happen. So, is there any way 'excluding' getting current page title (which can change in future) to separate function calling according to page calling.

Comment: One solution to provide that is to add a class/id to the body and act on it. E.g. your pages all generate html of the form `<body id="contracts" class="add">` it also doesn't couple your js tightly to the server side logic.

Comment: sorry AD7, i didn't udnderstand what are u trying explain. How do i use body tag id's/class to call single function

Comment: Do you know how to get the id and/or class properties of the body element and write an if statement in js? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current page URI will be in [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location), the current page title will be in [`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.title).

Comment: in this case if my page name changes in future i have to change my variable value too, which is not a option for me :(

Comment: I'm not sure if you're being facetious - this answers exactly what you've asked. What you point out is an (obvious) problem with what you're asking, not this answer. +1